# Save button doesn't trigger event in the first click Blazor Web Assembly Edit form

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

So, I have an `EditForm` Component which has `InputText` Component which triggers the `onFieldChanged` event. Also, I have a button that is using the `OnValidSubmit EventCallback<EditContext>`, which then submits the form. The problem is that if the `InputText` is focused and I try to click the Save button, it doesn't trigger on the first click because it calls first the `FieldChanged` event, and does not call the `OnValidSubmit` event, on the second click it works. It also works if you click somewhere else then in the button, but clicking after the `InputText` doesn't work.

How can I make it so it calls the `onValidSubmit` after the `fieldchangedEvent`?

Thanks in advance.

Edit

The component EditFormBody:

```
@inherits ComponentBase 
@typeparam TItem
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">@Title</h4>
    <div class="panel-heading-btn">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle" data-click="panel-expand"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="@BodyCss">

        @if (ShowWait)
        {
            <PleaseWait />
        }
        else
        {
            <EditForm  EditContext="@FormEditContext" OnValidSubmit="@OnSave">
                <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.ValidationSummary />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        @ChildContent

                    </div>
                </div>
               
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-1" tabindex="51" disabled="@IsReadOnly">Save</button>
                           
                        </div>
                    
                </div>
            </EditForm>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

```
@code {


[Parameter] public TItem Model { get; set; }

[Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
[Parameter] public RenderFragment LeftButtons { get; set; }


[Parameter] public bool IsReadOnly { get; set; }
[Parameter] public bool ShowCancel { get; set; } = true;

[Parameter] public EventCallback<EditContext> OnValidSubmit { get; set; }
[Parameter] public EventCallback Cancel { get; set; }
[Parameter] public EventCallback<string> PropertyChanged { get; set; }


private EditContext FormEditContext { get; set; }
private bool ShowWait { get; set; } = true;

protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync ()
{
    if (Model != null)
    {
        FormEditContext = new EditContext(Model);
        FormEditContext.OnFieldChanged += OnChange;
        ShowWait = false;
    }
    await base.OnParametersSetAsync();
}
private void OnChange (object sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.FieldIdentifier.FieldName != "CurrentValue")
        PropertyChanged.InvokeAsync(e.FieldIdentifier.FieldName);

}
private async Task OnSave (EditContext context)
{
    try
    {
     
        ShowWait = true;
        await OnValidSubmit.InvokeAsync(context);
        ShowWait = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ShowWait = false;
        await this.ShowErrorMessage(JS, Title, ex);
    }
   
}
private async Task Delete ()
{
    try
    {
        ShowWait = true;
        await OnValidSubmit.InvokeAsync(null);
        ShowWait = false;

        //await this.NavigateTo(ReturnUrl);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ShowWait = false;
        await this.ShowErrorMessage(JS, Title, ex);
    }
}}
```

The form where i call the component:

```
<EditFormBody Model="@CurrentObject" Mode="@Mode" Title="@Title" ReturnUrl="/administration/users" OnValidSubmit="@Save" Cancel="Cancel">
        <ChildContent>
            <InputText  @bind-Value="@CurrentObject.Email" />
        </ChildContent>
    </EditFormBody>
```

Comment: Did you try to use a binding for the TextInput instead of the onFieldChanged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a bare bones version of your code.  This works in my test environment - Blazor Server project built from the template.  I've looked at your code and can't see the issue at the moment.  I suggest you take this barebones version, check it works, then build it up unitl you break it. Good luck.

```cs
// BasicEditor.razor
@page "/basiceditor"
<BasicEditorCard EditContext="_EditContext" OnValidSubmit="ValidatedSubmit">
    <InputText @bind-Value="model.Email"></InputText>
</BasicEditorCard>
<div>@message</div>

@code {

    public class Model
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    private EditContext _EditContext;

    private Model model { get; set; } = new Model() { Email = "me@you.com" };

    private string message = "Not yet clicked";

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _EditContext = new EditContext(model);
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    private Task ValidatedSubmit(EditContext editContext)
    {
        message = $"clicked at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

```cs
// BasicEditorCard.razor
<EditForm EditContext="EditContext" OnValidSubmit="ValidatedSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    @ChildContent
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>
<div>@message</div>

@code {

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public EditContext EditContext { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<EditContext> OnValidSubmit { get; set; }

    private string message = "No";

    private Task ValidatedSubmit()
    {
        OnValidSubmit.InvokeAsync(EditContext);
        message = $"clicked at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

## Update

You have a two problems:

Reversed Logic

```cs
protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync ()
{
    // should be if (Model is null)
    if (Model != null)
    {
        FormEditContext = new EditContext(Model);
        FormEditContext.OnFieldChanged += OnChange;
        ShowWait = false;
    }
    await base.OnParametersSetAsync();
}
```

Your logic is the wrong way round!  Every time a parameter changes you are creating a new EditContext.

Generics

Using generics is also causing a problem. `EditContext` takes an `object`, so you can do away with the generics in the Component and simply declare `Model` as follows, losing `@typeparam TItem` in the process:

```cs
[Parameter] public object Model { get; set; }
```

My final prototype version of your component looks like this:

```cs
@implements IDisposable
<EditForm EditContext="EditContext" OnValidSubmit="ValidatedSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    @ChildContent
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>
<div>@message</div>
@code {

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public object Model { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<EditContext> OnValidSubmit { get; set; }
    private string message = "No";
    protected EditContext EditContext;

    protected override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (this.EditContext is null)
        {
            EditContext = new EditContext(Model);
            EditContext.OnFieldChanged += this.OnFieldChanged;
        }
        return base.OnParametersSetAsync();
    }

    private void OnFieldChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var x = true;
    }

    private Task ValidatedSubmit()
    {
        OnValidSubmit.InvokeAsync(EditContext);
        message = $"clicked at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
      => EditContext.OnFieldChanged -= this.OnFieldChanged;
}
```

On a different subject, you should be able to lose the Javascript in toggling the card content by using similar techniques to what you've already used in the wait. Here's my `UIShow` component that should point you in the right direction. A button/anchor to toggle a boolean property?

```cs
@if (this.Show)
{
    @this.ChildContent
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public bool Show { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

One of my Blazor mantra's/commandments is "Thou shalt not write Javascript"!

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I changed the TItem model to object, again it didn't work. However, when i changed the edit context and took it from the page i call the component it is working. I am still not sure why though, what is the problem if i don't send the context via [Parameter] but i send it as a parameter in the OnSave method ?

Comment: @Irvin - talk about all of us missing the blindingly obvious,  see my updated answer.